# Calculate a date with reference to multiple cells and with multiple conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel

Cell A1 has joining date
Cell B1 has last date of work
Cell C1 has start date of new leave

Call C2 has to calculate a date based on year of cell C1 but the day and month should be the anniversary date based on cell A1
Another condition to this is the date in cell C2 cannot exceed cell B1

Please help with the formula

Answer (score 2):

So the core mechanic you want is:

```
=DATE(YEAR(C1), MONTH(A1), DAY(A1))
```

We can't just say `=year(C1) + month(a1) + day(a1)` because it would undergo date addition in that context, whereas if you use the =date(year, month, day) method, it correctly interprets what you're going for.

Next we'll want to add the if syntax, which is basically going to be like this:

```
=if(date1 > date2, "True", "False")
```

The complete equation will essentially take the previous new date, and calculate it twice (because it can't self-reference easily), once in the conditional and again for the result if there wasn't a rule violation:

```
=if(DATE(YEAR(C1), MONTH(A1), DAY(A1)) > B1, "Error!", DATE(YEAR(C1), MONTH(A1), DAY(A1)))
```

Comment: The formula works only if the month of joining date (A1)is lesser than the month of the start date of new leave in C1. If the month in C1 is July and the month of joining date is March it does a reverse calculation for the next date. How do we fix that?

Comment: @HRCVS Sorry I missed your comment. If you need to layer logic together, you can have nested IF statements. See [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-nested-formulas-and-avoiding-pitfalls-0b22ff44-f149-44ba-aeb5-4ef99da241c8) for examples and best practices. In summary, try not to use too many nested statements in one cell, you can use additional worksheets in the tabs at the bottom of your UI if you want to do interim calculations and comparisons out-of-view.